# OverlapCircleAll optimization

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made boids in unity but when trying to render a 1000 of them the performance is really bad, in my update function i use Physics.OverlapCircleAll to check all surroundiing boids. Is there any way to do this more optimized? Here is my update function:

```
void Update()
    {
        Collider2D[] hitColliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(Position, radius,layerMask.value);
        List<Boid> boids = hitColliders.Select(o => o.GetComponent<Boid>()).ToList();
        boids.Remove(this);
        Flock(boids.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: Why iterate to a list just to remove one item and then iterate again to array? Simply use `var boids = hitColliders.Select(o => o.GetComponent<Boid>()).Where(o => o != this).ToArray();` .. in general though it sounds like you could even store the references in a `Dictionary<Collider, Boid>` .. however either way if this is called on 1000 objects it will always have a quite huge performance impact .. imagine only 3ms .. on 1000 object becomes 3000ms ...

Comment: I'ld recommend to use the [Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerWindow.html), enable `Deep Profile` and see what exactly is the most performance consuming thing in your method (e.g. we don't know what your final goal is or what `Flock` does exactly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely! Physics.OverlapCircleAll creates a lot of garbage every time it is called. What you're looking for is [Physics.OverlapCircleNonAlloc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircleNonAlloc.html), which will not create any garbage as it uses a buffer:

```
Collider2D[] hitsBuffer = new Collider2D[30]; //limit the amout of possible boid interations

void Update()
{
    int numHits = Physics2D.OverlapCircleNonAlloc(Position, radius, hitsBuffer, layerMask.value);
    Flock(hitsBuffer,numHits);
}

void Flock(Collider2D[] hitsBuffer, int numHits){

    for(int i = 0; i < numHits; i++){
        var boid = hitsBuffer[i].GetComponent<Boid>();
        if(boid == this)
            continue;
        //flocking algorith here
    }
}
```

Note how in the above code no additional arrays are created each frame, which is quite expensive. To check how much time is being spent where check out the Profiler:

- Orange is 'Physics', working out the overlaps
- Cyan is 'Scripts', calcuations in code, ie the flocking algorithm
- Dark green is 'GarbageCollector', handling arrays created and destroyed each frame

PS If not already, ensure that the boids are using a CircleCollider2D, this is the easiest for Unity to calculate.

PPS You may want to double check that `if(boid == this)` actually gets called. I thought that `Physics.Overlap...` ignores *this* collider.